# eclipse debugger treating my user input as cmds not inputs to my programs

Tags: c++, eclipse, cin

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello once more" << endl; // prints !!!Hello once more

     string word1 = "a";
     string word2 = "b";

     cout << "enter two words "<< endl;
     cin >> word1 >> word2;
     while(true) {
         cout << word1 << word2 << endl;
         cout << "enter two words "<< endl;
         cin >> word1 >> word2;

     }
}
```

This should read two words in a line separated by space and store them in my string, and then print them out again. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/, the `cin` extractor considers space as separators.

Here is a screenshot of my debugger and its output before I hit `cin`:

[image]

The first pic is my debugger before we read user input.

The next pic is what happens after I put the input `jack jill` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Why is my debugger treating my user input as a command? I thought the console is where I interact with my program?

I tested the program itself.  If I use the `.exe`, it works fine. If I use Eclipse's debugger, it craps out, so this is probably an Eclipse debugger issue.

Comment: IIRC the built in console in Eclipse is only for commands to the debugger, so you need to enable an "use external console" option. I don't remember where it is since it's been a while since I used Eclipse but if you look around you should find it.

Comment: ok finally! thanks this lead me to the right path

Answer (score 1):

Your program appears to work for me.
The reason for the error is that `jack jill` is being interpreted as commands by your debugging program.
Notice the `Undefined command "jack" try "help".` error message.

Try compiling without debug mode enabled.
Here's the output from cpp.sh:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in debug configuration set to use external debugger. screenshots included.[image]

[image]